# Restore background color of laptop Windows 10 OS 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, notepad++, colors

I am getting irritated with dark theme as background in my windows laptop. Which ever app I opened, I am seeing dark mode(Black color) . I never got this before. I am not sure how it happened without my knowledge.

I tried to change colors(dark to Light Mode vice versa) , ease of access, personalized in window settings. Nothing helped me.

**I am using my official laptop. My computer basic window information is below : (My windows is activated)**
[image]

Below are sample screenshots.

Kindly help me to restore to normal settings.

**Visual Studio:**

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Background Color]

**Notepad++:**
[image: Notepad++ Background Color]

**Notepad:**
[image: Notepad background Color]
**File Explorer ribbon/tabs:**
[image: File Explorer Ribbon/tab names]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not set Windows to use the Dark theme, then it might have
been that the registry setting for the default background color of all
windows was changed from the default color of white to black.

To verify:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`
- In the right pane of the Colors key, double-click the item named
  `Window`
- The default RGB value is `255 255 255` for the color white,
  but yours may have been reset to `0`.
- Reset the value to `255 255 255` (with the separating blanks)
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked :)